# how to convert array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can i convert first array to second with lodash ?

From :

```
var data = [
  {'column':[1,1,1,1,1]},
  {'column':[2,2,2,2,2]},
  {'column':[3,3,3,3,3]},
]
```

To :

```
var data = [
  {'column':[1,2,3]},
  {'column':[1,2,3]},
  {'column':[1,2,3]},
  {'column':[1,2,3]},
  {'column':[1,2,3]},
]
```

Comment: does it have to be lodash? Can it be done without a third-part lib?

Comment: no actually i just want to learn with lodash what is your solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var data = [
  {'column':[1,1,1,1,1]},
  {'column':[2,2,2,2,2]},
  {'column':[3,3,3,3,3]},
];

var newData = _(data)
  .map('column')
  .unzip()
  .map(function(col) {
    return {'column': col};
  })
  .value();

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```